# Eclipse Helios: Java EE Perspective: How to have jars added to build path under one hood like referenced library

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a GWT+Spring+Hibernate project and so I have several jars in WEB-INF/lib directory. All of these jars are added to build path. I get unconvenient view for jars in build path like

```
MY_Project
|->src
|->resource
|->JRE System Library[jdk1.6]
|->ant.jar   //from here on jars in build path
|->asm-common.jar
|->asm-util.jar
|->c3p0.jar
|->commons-collections.jar
 .
 .
 .
```

and this list goes on for 40 more jars here to cover up full screen length. Consequently I can't navigate to other dependent project easily.

I would like here something like what I get when I switch to spring perspective:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MY_Project
|->src
|->resource
|->JRE System Library[jdk1.6]
|->Referenced Libraries //<-- here goes all that 40 jars under on hood
|->war
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So any suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Switch to Package Explorer View (instead of Project Explorer
   View)
2. If it doesn't show "Referenced Libraries" in Package
   Explorer View, click on the downward pointing triangle in the view
   and ensure "Show 'Referenced Libraries' Node" is ticked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `Window` -> `Preferences`.
2. There select `Java` -> `Build Path` -> `User Libraries`.
3. Enter name for the library.
4. Add all relevant jars.

From then on the library can be added for any specific project via: `right click on your project` -> `Build Path` -> `Configure`. Select `Libraries` tab -> `Add Library` -> `User Library`.

Enjoy!

Comment: Hey thanks Boris, I knew that but while working with GWT (specially RequestFactory) for some reason I need jars in lib. I know its not usual case but I would like to know if there is any other workaround